# There is no change to the second activity element when intending

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-intent

I made a simple application using Kotlin. I want to change pages. I create a new Activity and call it from the MainActivity. When I run AVD, then switch pages, the page displayed is empty. There are no elements at all like new Activities.

And this is the intent code for the second Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    already_have_account_text_view.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Try to login activity")

        //launch the login activity
        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

LoginActivity code:

```
package com.example.kotlinmessanger

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class LoginActivity: AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }
}
```

And this is the xml of the second Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="#8BC34A"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_edittext_login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="E-mail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edittext_login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/email_edittext_login"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/email_edittext_login"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_edittext_login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button_login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password_edittext_login"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/password_edittext_login"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_edittext_login" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add the code for `LoginActivity` in question /

Comment: Looks like you have a layout problem.

Comment: please check my answer below it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/61290106/12386821

Answer (score 0):

Please change width of  `android:layout_width="0dp"`  0dp to Any specific width of all the EditText and Button and add some proper width to them